# Can I use an SQL DECLARE section at global scope in Pro*C?

Tags: c, oracle-pro-c, embedded-sql

I am trying to port a ~2000 line Pro*C program to C++ *(Pro*C++)*. It is full of global variables being used as host variables in SQL queries:

```
char var1;
char var2;

int execute_query() {

    // some code

    EXEC SQL SELECT ... INTO :var1
    EXEC SQL SELECT ... INTO :var2

    // some code

}
```

However, with `code=cpp` in the precompiler options, the `PARSE` option is set to `PARTIAL`, meaning the precompiler only recognises host variables declared in a `DECLARE` section.

Can I just surround the global variables with a declare section?

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION

   char var1;
   char var2;

EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION

int execute_query() {

    // some code

    EXEC SQL SELECT ... INTO :var1
    EXEC SQL SELECT ... INTO :var2

    // some code

}
```

If not, is there another way to make the precompiler recognise the global variables without doing a lot of refactoring?

Comment: What happened when you tried wrapping them in a declare section?

Comment: I asked because there were many hurdles in making a standalone test program in my environment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

After much fiddling around, I finally managed to create a standalone Pro*C program to test this out, and I can confirm that it works.